# Next.Js unwanted repeating background

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, next.js

I'm new to Next.Js but I have used it before. However, when I add a new javascript file and add a basic header or paragraph it repeats its padding, going down the webpage. I was following a tutorial on how to use Next.js. All they did was add a new javascript file and added a heading but this didn't happen to them. They had version 11 while I have version 13. I added a picture to show exactly what I am facing
[image]

this is all i added

```
function Test(){
    return (<h1 >test</h1>)
}

export default Test
```

globals.css

```
:root {
  --max-width: 1100px;
  --border-radius: 12px;
  --font-mono: ui-monospace, Menlo, Monaco, 'Cascadia Mono', 'Segoe UI Mono',
    'Roboto Mono', 'Oxygen Mono', 'Ubuntu Monospace', 'Source Code Pro',
    'Fira Mono', 'Droid Sans Mono', 'Courier New', monospace;

  --foreground-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  --background-start-rgb: 214, 219, 220;
  --background-end-rgb: 255, 255, 255;

  --primary-glow: conic-gradient(
    from 180deg at 50% 50%,
    #16abff33 0deg,
    #0885ff33 55deg,
    #54d6ff33 120deg,
    #0071ff33 160deg,
    transparent 360deg
  );
  --secondary-glow: radial-gradient(
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 1),
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)
  );

  --tile-start-rgb: 239, 245, 249;
  --tile-end-rgb: 228, 232, 233;
  --tile-border: conic-gradient(
    #00000080,
    #00000040,
    #00000030,
    #00000020,
    #00000010,
    #00000010,
    #00000080
  );

  --callout-rgb: 238, 240, 241;
  --callout-border-rgb: 172, 175, 176;
  --card-rgb: 180, 185, 188;
  --card-border-rgb: 131, 134, 135;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
    --foreground-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
    --background-start-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
    --background-end-rgb: 0, 0, 0;

    --primary-glow: radial-gradient(rgba(1, 65, 255, 0.4), rgba(1, 65, 255, 0));
    --secondary-glow: linear-gradient(
      to bottom right,
      rgba(1, 65, 255, 0),
      rgba(1, 65, 255, 0),
      rgba(1, 65, 255, 0.3)
    );

    --tile-start-rgb: 2, 13, 46;
    --tile-end-rgb: 2, 5, 19;
    --tile-border: conic-gradient(
      #ffffff80,
      #ffffff40,
      #ffffff30,
      #ffffff20,
      #ffffff10,
      #ffffff10,
      #ffffff80
    );

    --callout-rgb: 20, 20, 20;
    --callout-border-rgb: 108, 108, 108;
    --card-rgb: 100, 100, 100;
    --card-border-rgb: 200, 200, 200;
  }
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  max-width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  color: rgb(var(--foreground-rgb));
  background: linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      transparent,
      rgb(var(--background-end-rgb))
    )
    rgb(var(--background-start-rgb));
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  html {
    color-scheme: dark;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share the CSS you have applied the background with

Comment: @Harrison i didn't apply any CSS it's the one that comes default with Next.js. I was following a tutorial and this didn't happen to them. But i will update it with the default css

Comment: @Harrison I added the CSS

Comment: I know this was asked 6 months ago but the answers are almost all entirely wrong, it's due to your `body` element not taking up the whole page. Set your html and body elements to have a width of `100vw` and a height of `100vh` (no padding / margin to prevent overflow).

Answer (score 2):

Removing the following css gets rid of the effect... But I'm not exactly sure why it repeats like that down the page when you add a new html element to the page.

```
 background: linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      transparent,
      rgb(var(--background-end-rgb))
    )
    rgb(var(--background-start-rgb));
```

Answer (score 2):

go to globals.css and remove this:
`--background-start-rgb: 214, 219, 220;`
`--background-end-rgb: 255, 255, 255;`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I solved it by adding "min-h-screen" to my main tag (h1 in your case).

Tailwind CSS reference: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/min-height

Alternatively, set your min-height: 100vh in your CSS if you aren't using Tailwind

Comment: this worked for me. i wonder if they fixed the issue in latest versions

Answer (score 1):

```
body {
  color: rgb(var(--foreground-rgb));
  background: 
  linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    transparent,
    rgb(var(--background-end-rgb))
    )
}
```

The background creates a gradient effect in the body, but the effect of repeating the background is shown in `light` mode due to the different values of `var(--background-end-rgb)` and `var(--background-start-rgb)`.

In the case of `dark` mode, the **media preference color scheme** has the same color values for both variables; that's why this effect is not showing in dark mode.

So, if you want to remove this background repeat, there are **two steps**:

1. Make the values of both variables the same in `:root`
2. Remove the `linear gradient` code from the `background` property and give `variable` directly.

> `var(--background-end-rgb)` or `var(--background-start-rgb)` in this case, since both have the same value in the preferred color scheme.

If you want to play around with linear gradients, check out [CSS Gradient](https://cssgradient.io/).

**The final code will look like:**

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

:root {
  --foreground-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  --background-start-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
  --background-end-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
    --foreground-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
    --background-start-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
    --background-end-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  }
}

body {
  color: rgb(var(--foreground-rgb));
  background: rgb(var(--background-start-rgb));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include this to your `globals.css`.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set to body classname in layout.js "bg-no-repeat".

Like this:

```
<body className={`${inter.className} bg-no-repeat`}>{children}</body>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found the problem to be in the styling of the *body* element in globals.css file itself. Simply removing the **background** property's style results in a normal looking webpage.

```
body {
  color: rgb(var(--foreground-rgb));
  background: linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      transparent,
      rgb(var(--background-end-rgb))
    )
    rgb(var(--background-start-rgb));
}
```

Just remove the *background: linear-gradient* part.

Answer (score 0):

"--background-start-rgb: 214, 219, 220;
--background-end-rgb: 255, 255, 255;"

choose the same values for both